# Why are TIE Fighters' gun ports red, when they fire green lasers?

Tags: star-wars

Why are TIE Fighters' gun ports red, when they fire green lasers?

If you do a Google Images search for TIE Fighter, you'll see half of the TIE Fighters don't have any color on the gun ports, but half of them are colored red.  Some examples below:

[image: TIE Fighter]
[image: TIE Advanced]

Comment: Christmas illumination?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! While this might be a valid question it is best if you show your own research. The site allows for pictures to be embedded in posts, so you should do that Google Image Search and *show* us what you mean.

Comment: If memory serves re: blasters and lasers, they work by exciting gas into plasma. So, while the blaster gas and burning plasma are one colour, the "galven coils" through which the gas travels to become excited may have a differently coloured glow.

Comment: I doubt there is any answer to this beyond style, but its still seems to be a technically valid question.

Comment: Images added!  :)

Answer (score 2):

While there may be a completely different in-universe explanation, [dichroism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichroic_glass), i.e. having different colours in different lighting conditions, is a known real-life phenomenon. A particular examplary example is the [Lycurgus Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycurgus_Cup), which looks green when lit from in front, but glows red when lit from inside or behind.

This is of course exactly the reverse of the TIE fighters gun ports, but if you look at the picture below (from [dichroic filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichroic_filter) on Wikipedia), you will see that the left one lets through green light, but appears faintly purple -- a bit nearer to your observation.

[image]